# react-navigation for react-native-web?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation, react-native-web

Need to reuse the `react-navigation` code from mobile to `react-native-web`. But I could not able to get it work in web.

[image]

Should we need to use `react-router` for web separately?

How can we configure navigation commonly for both platform? 
I would love to see an example of this! It would be super helpful. Thank you!!

Comment: Did you find any working solution?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can check this implementation

[Using React Native, React Native Web and React Navigation in a single project](https://pickering.org/using-react-native-react-native-web-and-react-navigation-in-a-single-project-cfd4bcca16d0)

Comment: i also want to know, react-navigation lib will navigate in web but it also showing back button after navigation so if want to use the browser back button then how can i achieve for web